# TreeView with flat <li> structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a reusable TreeView component in AngularJS that takes following object as an input,

```
[
    {
        label: "1",
        children: [{
                label: "1.1",
                children: [{
                    label: "1.1.1",
                }]
            },
            {
                label: "1.2",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: "2
    }
]
```

And should render a TreeView for that. For number of reasons, I want generated HTML structure to be made of flat 'li'

E.g.

```
<ul>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 1.1 </li>
    <li> 1.1.1 </li>
    <li> 1.2 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
</ul>
```

Other Requirements:

- No programmatic flattening of the structure. It should be just a
  clever directive.
- Should go any level deep

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dspTB/1340/) to play with. So far I am able to render the first level only. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in Angular2 you can render directives recursively. This makes rendering the tree very easy. I've modified your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vd9XXAQTHXxkCXaSjUHb?p=preview) a little bit just to show the point. It's not the ideal implementation but it works as expected :).

Example:

```js
 @Component({
    selector: 'tree-view',
    template: '
        <div *ngFor="#dir of dirs">
            <tree-view [dirs]="dir.dirs"></tree-view>
        <div>
    ',
    directives: [TreeView]
})
export class TreeView {
    @Input() 
    private dirs: Array<Directory>;
}
```